# В чем смысл Code Contracts?

Tags: c#, .net

В чем смысл Code Contracts?

Со стороны похожи на на Assert'ы.

Где-то вычитал, что они помогают генерировать документацию. Только это их единственное преимущество?

Вроде, если я правильно понял, то и в Runtime производится проверка выполнения контрактов. Но в чем их преимущество перед стандартными if?

Исходники .NET напичканы этими контрактами.

Comment: Забить на все и кодить дальше чтоб работало

Comment: формализованные и прокачанные ассерты. Могут быть вырезаны из результирующей сборки, также могут быть подсказки в студии. Просто из-за роста времени компиляции не взлетело.

Comment: Контракты, по замыслу, должны в компайл-тайме проверять код.

Answer (score 3):

Боюсь этот вопрос выходит за рамки `Stackowerflow`, вы хотите чтобы вам сюда кусок текста из литературы кинули? Прочитайте хотя бы у Албахари главу 13 - большая ее часть посвящена контрактам. Если уж после чтения останутся какие-то конкретные вопросы - тогда уже можно будет их задать.

> **Обзор контрактов кода**
>
> Ранее мы упоминали о концепции *утверждения*, посредством которого осуществляется проверка того, что определенное условие удовлетворяется повсюду в программе. Если условие нарушается, то это указывает на ошибку, которая обычно обрабатывается путем запуска отладчика (в отладочных сборках) или генерации исключения (в окончательных сборках).
>
> Утверждения следуют принципу, что если уж произошла ошибка, то лучше сообщить об этом как можно раньше и ближе к ее источнику. Обычно это предпочтительнее попытки продолжить с недействительными данными, которая может привести к неправильным результатам, неожиданным побочным эффектам или генерации исключения позже в программе (все это гораздо труднее диагностировать).
>
> Исторически существуют два пути принудительного применения утверждений:
>
> • вызов метода `Assert` на объекте типа `Debug` или `Trace`;
>
> • генерация исключений (таких как `ArgumentNullException`).
>
> В `.NET Framework 4.0` появилось новое средство под названием *контракты кода*, которое заменяет оба подхода унифицированной системой. Эта система позволяет делать не только простые утверждения, но также и более мощные утверждения, основанные на *контрактах*.
>
> Контракты кода порождены от принципа контрактного программирования (`Design bу Contract`) на языке `Eiffel`, при котором функции взаимодействуют друг с другом через систему взаимных обязательств и преимуществ. По существу функция указывает *предусловия*, которые должны быть удовлетворены клиентом (вызывающим компонентом), и в ответ гарантирует соблюдение *постусловий*, от которых может зависеть клиент, когда функция завершится.
>
> Типы для контрактов кода находятся в пространстве имен `System.Diagnostics.Contracts`.